# non-UTF-8 string error public domain but not lcoalhost

Tags: node.js, utf-8

I am using GOOGLE API to get geometry values.

This is my piece of code:

```
const utf8 = require('utf8');

apiCreateShop.post('/', function(request, response) {

if (request.query.street && request.query.street_number && request.query.city && request.query.country && request.query.name && request.query.vendorID && request.query.description) {
        
        var url = utf8.encode('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + request.query.street + ' ' + request.query.street_number + ' ' + request.query.city + ' ' + request.query.country + '&key=key');
        
        var lat = "";
        var lng = "";
        http.get(url, (res) => {
            let body = "";
            res.on("data", (chunk) => {
                body += chunk;
            });
            res.on("end", () => {
                try {
                    let json = JSON.parse(body);
                    lat = json['results'][0].geometry.location['lat'];
                    lng = json['results'][0].geometry.location['lng'];
```

If I call the API using POSTMAN to my local development environment, I succeed.

[image]

Deploying the code to my test instance (domain), I fail, getting the following error:

> error_message:    'Invalid request. One of the input parameters
> contains a non-UTF-8 string.',

[image]

The error is the "Ü" for street passed in the parameters.

> {
> "message": "No data found" } //return if exception

I tried

> utf8.encode(string)

but it is not working. What is the issue here?

Comment: What is the actual problematic byte? The error message seems to indicate that the client submitted something in an unknown encoding (probably Latin-1) in which case failing is actually correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown here, the URL is invalid. [RFC 3986](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-2) defines what characters are allowed in each component. In the query component, only the following are allowed:

```
  query       = *( pchar / "/" / "?" )
  pchar         = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"
  unreserved    = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
  pct-encoded = "%" HEXDIG HEXDIG
  sub-delims  = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
              / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
```

Basically, that's a long way of saying "Latin, 0-9, and some symbols." `Ü` is not on that list. URLs are not UTF-8 encoded. They're US-ASCII encoded (i.e. "7-bit ASCII").

You're required to percent-encode other values. So `Ü` should be `%C3%9C`.

Different components have different rules.

Some servers are sloppy about what they accept, so sometimes raw UTF-8 will "work." But it's not valid, and not all servers will accept it.